# function with one argument called without any argument in python

Tags: python

I read this code in codeskulptor3

```
import simplegui

message = "Welcome!"

def click():
  global message
  message = "Good job!"


def draw(canvas):
  canvas.draw_text(message, [50,112], 48, "Red")

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 200)
frame.add_button("Click me", click)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
frame.start()
```

I don't understand why the function `draw` is being passed to `set_draw_handler` without any argument (it should take a canvas object). But I don't see any canvas object. Who pass it?

Comment: It's not being called yet.

Comment: Because **the function** is passed, **not** the result of calling it.

Comment: You're telling set_draw_handler "Hey, here's this function, I want you to call it **later**".

Comment: Later when? I don't see in being called

Answer (score -1):

`frame` is taking `draw` as a callback, and will call it and pass the canvas argument at appointed times.

Comment: But I don't  see any canvas argument? Who pass it?